# LogPoint normalization signature language reference

Tags: logging, normalization

Where can I find a reference for a language that is used for creating signature of normalization package in [LogPoint](https://www.logpoint.com/en/)?

Alternatively maybe you know this syntax:

```
<:time><severity:word>[<process:word>] [<object:string>]
```

What's this? Is there any reference document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a format whose reference is only available for Logpoint customers. The reference is found in the user manual in a chapter called 'Signatures' which is found at the [customer portal](https://customer.logpoint.com/).

Hint: the language does not resemble anything i know from earlier. If used correctly, it can still be very powerful.

Comment: From which version? I cannot see it in 5.3.0 from here: https://customer.logpoint.com/docs/5.3.0/download_pdf/user

Comment: Mine is for version 5.2.1. There should be a chapter called 'Signatures'.

Comment: Found it, thanks! It's chapter 10 in the newest version. I think it would be helpful if you update the answer with the chapter name instead of page numbers for any future references.

Answer (score 4):

```
<:time><severity:word>[<process:word>] [<object:string>]
```

The normal format for capturing the key-value pair is `<key:'regex_pattern'>`

However, Logpoint has come up with custom regex which replaces the plain old and cryptic regex with more human readable format. 
These custom regex are called "definers", you can go through the list of definers and what they capture at the appendix section of the document. Some definers used by logpoint is : int, float, word, words etc.

Now regarding the former part of a regex pattern "key" in `<"key":'definer'>`, 
The "key" is a set of vocabulary which is set as standard name which is bind with the value from the log. LogPoint has some hundreds of key words which is logically enough to capture the values from almost all of the logs.

Significance of maintaining standard key pool

System A  has its logs as:

```
4-5-15 domain:3456 src_add:10.0.1.12 src_prt:80 dst_add:10.0.1.30 dst_prt:100
```

System B has its logs as:

```
4-5-15 domain:3456 source address:10.0.1.12 source port:80 destination address:10.0.1.30 dstination port:100
```

In these two example, the `src_add` and `source address` are mapped to `source_address` regardless of how they were represented on logs. This uniformity in capturing values helps to create a robust intelligence system, so next time you want to see the origin of traffic throughout your system, you can just type in

```
source_address={filter value}
```

and monitor the devices.

Let me know if there is some more confusion.

Ex-employee, LogPoint